# Windows Phone 8 - Run XNA in higher resolution

Tags: c#, .net, xna, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

We have an XNA game, that is meant to run on Windows Phone 8 as well as 7.1.

Everything in-game works on higher resolution phones like WXGA, but our game runs at 800x480 since that is the only supported size for WP7.

Is there a way to detect higher res phones for XNA and set the `PreferredBackBufferWidth` and `PreferredBackbufferHeight` appropriately?

Or is there basically not a way to do this with the available XNA support on Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XNA may not support this but it looks like MonoGame (open source port of XNA which works on WP8) will support the higher resolutions. See [Nokia's topic on MonoGame and WP8](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/XNA_Games_On_Windows_Phone_8_with_Monogame) for a primer.

Comment: Do you know if MonoGame supports WP7?  We already use MonoGame for iOS, Windows 8, and Android.

Comment: Is there a way on Windows store to upload 2 apps: a MonoGame one for WP8 and an XNA one for WP7? The problem is right now there are alot more WP7 phones, but we want WP8 working properly for the future.

Comment: Yes you can submit different XAP files which targets different types of devices for the same project, I don't think it should matter if one is XNA and one is a MonoGame. Check out this blog post: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/01/15/app-submission-tips-for-windows-phone-7-and-windows-phone-8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to port your game to DirectX for WP8 to support higher resolutions.