# Changing resolution in XNA WP8 C#

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-8

I'm writing a game in XNA 4.0 with C# for Windows Phone 8.

How can I change Resolution or VirtualResolution (I have no idea how to call it)? I was looking in the web, but couldn't find the correct answer.

I found (1):

```
Resolution.SetVirtualResolution(1280, 720);
Resolution.SetResolution(800, 600, false);
```

and (2)

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth  = 1024;
graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

The (1) I have no idea how to use it, and the (2) doesn't work. I have resolution 800x480 in WP8 Emulator and I can't change it.

Comment: Maybe emulator doesn't allow resolutions higher than (or different from) its default. If you can, you should try doing this on an actual WP8 device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8 - Run XNA in higher resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364457/windows-phone-8-run-xna-in-higher-resolution)